# Containerized Apache co-exisitng with host Apache

Tags: docker, virtualhost, friendly-url

I have some web applications under same domain and different sub-domain running on same machine. I am using Apache Virtual Host configuration to use pretty URLs for all these applications. I am now trying to Dockerize one of these applications. So I exposed ports 80 and 443 to different ports of host machine.

I can successfully access containerized web application using URL format http://localhost:{http exposed port} OR https://localhost:{https exposed port}.

Now, If I try using Virtual host configuration within container it does not work unless I stop host machine Apache server.

How do I setup pretty URLs for containerized application using ports exposed from within container, along with running an Apache server on same machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse proxy will be the good option for run multiple docker containers which will be exposed on different different ports but will be configured on same port in reverse proxy. This link will be helpful, mentioned just below:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-with-mod_proxy-on-ubuntu-16-04

You can try one thing also just expose your application on different IP and configure that ip in /etc/hosts. Please check it here:

http://jasani.org/posts/docker-now-supports-adding-host-mappings-2014-11-19/index.html